# Stack Exchange button on top left corner is not showing all subscribed communities

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, top-bar, communities-list

I noticed that the top left drop-down menu does not show all my communities. If possible, I would rather see all my communities rather than an advertisement for the communities I could join. I can search for that myself.

(What made me finally ask this question is the fact that in the same drop-down menu that lists joined communities the click opens a new tab, and it is annoying to me. Just a side note.)

Comment: If you mean the *Your communities* list:  You can edit that list yourself and add/remove sites as you wish. I certainly don't want that to include all sites  I have an account on because I joined a lot of sites ...

Comment: I mean: "the top left drop-down menu". It reads: "StackExchange".  If you click it you get a drop-down menu.  There you find the communities you're subscribed to.

Comment: Just hit [edit in the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XW0K.png) and expand as much as you like...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a nice idea when you are a member of only six communities. For someone like me, the list would be ... a little longer. :)

We cap the default number of communities shown to 5 for that reason. As rene mentioned in the comments, however, you can edit the list to include all of your sites if you'd rather have them all included.

Comment: not intuitive. but thanks for answering.  problem solved. annoyance overcome.